# Are the methods for learning English reported on Antimoon reasonable?

Tags: self-learning, english

Antimoon (see e.g. [How to learn English](http://www.antimoon.com/how/howtolearn.htm)) claims that two Polish men ([Tomasz P. Szynalski and his friend MRW](http://www.antimoon.com/blog/about/)) taught themselves English primarily without studying rules and grammar.  Instead they read, listened, and used SRS methods.  As non-native writers they are quite remarkable.  Does anyone have any experience with this approach that would evaluate its usefulness?

Comment: Interesting question, and welcome to Language Learning Stack Exchange. Could you please add a link to a more detailed description of this "method"? (And possibly add a few more details to your question?) As it stands, there is not enough information to know how it works - just a list of techniques, but not how they are meant to work together, how much time you should spend on each etcetera.

Comment: How do you measure usefulness? Any method that results in learning a language can be considered equally "useful" to another.

Answer (score 2):

The Antimoon website describes various techniques for learning English:

- **[Motivation](http://www.antimoon.com/how/motiv.htm)**: the focus here is on what you can achieve when you learn English (see [Why learn English](http://www.antimoon.com/other/whylearn.htm)) and only to a lesser degree on motivational techniques. The authors state that you need to enjoy learning English; as a motivational technique they recommend [imagining yourself in the future](http://www.antimoon.com/how/lovelearn.htm) when you already know English.
- The authors point out that you should have a [good monolingual English **dictionary**](http://www.antimoon.com/how/dict.htm) and that you should look for a [learner's dictionary](http://www.antimoon.com/how/dictionary.htm). This is sound advice.
- They claim that you should [learn English **without mistakes**](http://www.antimoon.com/how/mistakes.htm), that you should avoid bad (linguistic) habits. They give some advice on how to do this (e.g. speak carefully and slowly; use simple language; look things up in a dictionary). Tomasz Synalski admits that his emphasis on avoiding mistakes is [controversial](http://www.antimoon.com/how/mistakes-in-learning.htm).
- They stress the importance of [studying English **pronunciation**](http://www.antimoon.com/how/pronunc.htm); this includes choosing between [American and British English](http://www.antimoon.com/how/pronunc-american-british.htm) and looking up the pronunciation of words. Correct pronunciation is also emphasised in Gabriel Wyner's book [*Fluent Forever*](https://fluent-forever.com/the-book/) but Wyner recommended adding sound files (e.g. from Forvo.com) to your flashcards.
- They stress the importance of getting a lot of [**input**](http://www.antimoon.com/how/input.htm). For grammar, input is more important than [relying on grammar rules](http://www.antimoon.com/how/input-gramrules.htm). The importance of input was also stressed in [Stephen Krashen's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Krashen) language learning theory; Krashen's stressed the importance of [*comprehensible* input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_hypothesis), not just any input. Using lots of example sentences to learn grammar patterns is also a technique recommended by Gabriel Wyner (see *Fluent Forever*, above). Szynalski even tries to estimate [how much input you need to become fluent in English](http://www.antimoon.com/how/input-howmuch.htm).
- The authors recommend using [**spaced-repetition software** (SRS)](http://www.antimoon.com/how/srs.htm). This advice will also sound familiar to readers of Wyner's book *Fluent Forever*.

Most of this is reasonable and useful but I missed (or overlooked) how it fits together as a method, i.e. a consistent view of how the individual techniques should be combined along a specific path. Language itself or individual language materials do not provide such a path, so if you are new to learning foreign languages, you may need some more guidance on how to get started.